# how can I make my box respond to any screen size

Tags: html, css

If you check my [PEN](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/YpWvKo) I am trying to create a responsive box.

At the moment,If I scale down the page, the items will start hiding.
Is there a way I can make this green box adjust to any mobile screen size?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-details">
      <div class="bo1">
        <img src="" alt="VISA ICON" class="visa">
        <input type="text" >
      </div>
      <div class="bo2">
        <p class="card-number" >CARD NUMBER</p>
        <input class="card-input" type="text" />
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="deposit-now" style="color:white" >DEPOSIT NOW</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
}
.card-details{
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
.card-details .bo1 input{
  float: right;
}
.card-details a.deposit-now{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 20px;
}
```

Hope you can help.

Comment: Use bootstrap or such type of framework which are providing these type of facilities by default otherwise for managing all the elements you will have to write lots of extra code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply a width of 100% and a max-width of 500px:

```
.card-details{
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOXjMO

Comment: Width of 100%. ABSOLUTELY YES

Answer (score 0):

Changing `width: 500px;` to `max-width: 500px;` at `.card-details` will adjust the width.

If you want to adjust the height you probably will have to change height to auto or try with flexbox or media queries

Answer (score 0):

Change `width` to `max-width` in your `.card-details` element.

Do

```
.card-details {
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

Instead of

```
.card-details {
  width: 500px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Alvaro answer would suit better for this particular because I will have content outside the green box that must full width.
Appreciate the support.

Answer (score 0):

**Without any media query you have use this.**

```css
   .container{
      width: 600px;
      max-width: 100%;
      background-color: blue;
      margin: auto;
    }
    .card-details{
      position: relative;
      background: green;
      border-radius: 10px;
      width: 80%;
      height: 250px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .card-details .bo1 input{
      float: right;
    }
    .card-details a.deposit-now{
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="card-details">
          <div class="bo1">
            <img src="" alt="VISA ICON" class="visa">
            <input type="text" >
          </div>
          <div class="bo2">
            <p class="card-number" >CARD NUMBER</p>
            <input class="card-input" type="text" />
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="deposit-now" style="color:white" >DEPOSIT NOW</a> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .container{
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
}
.card-details{
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  max-width:500px;
  height:250px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
.card-details .bo1 input{
  float: right;
}
.card-details a.deposit-now{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="card-details">
      <div class="bo1">
        <img src="" alt="VISA ICON" class="visa">
        <input type="text" >
      </div>
      <div class="bo2">
        <p class="card-number" >CARD NUMBER</p>
        <input class="card-input" type="text" />
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="deposit-now" style="color:white" >DEPOSIT NOW</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this does fine. First, of all I included the row and column in the container such that it is adjusted even for extra small size screen. Secondly, You will have to remove the width and height of the card-details class.